# Is there an equivalent to sed-style substitution commands from vim?

Tags: regular-expressions, replace, evil, vim-emulation

One of the things I miss from vim is being able to type in a substitution command that will work over multiple lines, for example:

```
:/begin/,/end/s/foo/bar/g
```

The above command substitutes "foo" for "bar" starting with the first line containing "begin" and ending with the next line after that containing "end".

Is there a way to do something similar in emacs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`evil` provides a stripped-down version of `ex`, so it's probably best to presume that it's not an exact drop-in.  However, the example you provided works out of the box, provided that point is *prior* to the first line (ie, the `begin` line in your example).

Comment: In vim the search would also start at point, so that sounds like what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Here is one way of doing it that uses built-in functionality only:

1. With point in the line that contains first occurrence of `begin`, press <kbd>C-SPC</kbd>.
2. Move to next occurrence of `end`:

   <kbd>C-s</kbd> `end` <kbd>RET</kbd>
3. Replace `foo` with `bar`:

   <kbd>M-%</kbd> `foo` <kbd>RET</kbd> `bar` <kbd>RET</kbd> <kbd>!</kbd>

This makes use of the fact that [`query-replace`](http://doc.endlessparentheses.com/Fun%2Fquery-replace.html) will work on the active region instead of the whole buffer if there is one.

---

Of course, you can also define a custom command:

```el
(defun replace-from-to (beg end str repl)
  (interactive "sBegin: \nsEnd: \nsString: \nsReplacement: ")
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (let ((start-pos (search-forward beg))
          (end-pos (search-forward end)))
      (replace-string str repl nil start-pos end-pos))))
```

This command will always search from the beginning of the buffer, so point can be after `begin`/`foo`/`end` when you invoke it.

Set up a key binding for it via:

```el
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c r") 'replace-from-to)
```

Answer (score 5):

In general, this is something that you would use `narrow-to-region` for.

You move the cursor (for example, by searching) to the beginning of the region and press `C-SPC`, then move to the end of the region and type `M-x narrow-to-region`. Now you can issue any search and replace commands that you want and they will only apply to narrowed part of the buffer. Once you're done, type `M-x widen` to restore the buffer content.

Comment: If `begin`/`end` are delimiters in a programming language, you can likely use `C-M-Space` to run `mark-sexp` to select the region in one command.

Comment: Default bindings: `C-x n n` (`narrow-to-region`) and `C-x n w` (`widen`).

Answer (score 0):

Nine years late, but I was looking for something like this, too. I wanted to be able to run sed-style regex commands in emacs the way I do from the ex command line in vim. `evil-mode`'s ex-like functionality sort of hits the spot, as mentioned above, but I don't really want to use evil. Running `sed` commands on selected regions or buffers is all I really need. So I tossed together a package this morning that does this. You can find it at [https://github.com/oblivia-simplex/emacs-sedition.git](https://github.com/oblivia-simplex/emacs-sedition), or install it with `straight.el` (or any other `use-package` extension that lets you pull from git repos). Once I've had a chance to kick the tires a little, I'll publish it on MELPA.

Here's the function that does all the work:

```
    (defun sedition ()
      "Pipe the contents of the region to the unix tool sed.
When called interactively, `REGION-BEGINNING' and `REGION-END'
refer to the beginning and end points of the active region.
If no region is active, they are set to the beginning and end of
the current buffer."
      (interactive)
      (let* ((in-region (use-region-p))
         (start (if in-region (region-beginning) (point-min)))
         (end (if in-region (region-end) (point-max)))
         (prompt (if in-region
                 (format "sed (region %d-%d): " start end)
                   "sed buffer: "))
             (command (read-string prompt nil 'sed--command-history))
         ;; generate-new-buffer will create a unique name with this prefix
         ;; the initial space hides it from list-buffers and buffer-menu
         ;; commands
         (tmpbuffer (generate-new-buffer " *sed*"))
         (exitcode (call-process-region start
                        end
                        "sed"
                        nil ;; don't delete anything yet
                        tmpbuffer
                        t
                        command)))
        ;; We only want to perform any action on the region/buffer
        ;; if the command succeeded, so check the exit code here.
        (cond ((zerop exitcode)
           (delete-region start end)
           (goto-char start)
           (insert-buffer-substring tmpbuffer))
          ((= exitcode 127)
           (message "sed: command not found"))
          ((= exitcode 1)
           (message "sed: error in command '%s'" command))
          ((stringp exitcode)
           (message "sed: %s" exitcode))
          (t (message "sed: exited with code %d" exitcode))
          )
        (kill-buffer tmpbuffer)))
```